# Azure Web App Authorization: session variables for auth/me

Tags: c#, azure

I am new to Azure web authentication and was wondering what I am doing incorrectly?

Home/index is default route.

I have this function capturing the /.auth/me info:

```js
var mobileClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(functionAppBaseUrl);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            mobileClient.invokeApi(`${functionAppBaseUrl}.auth/me`,
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'accept': 'application/json',
                        'content-type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(`Response from .auth/me: ${response.responseText}`);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("Auth", "Home")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { login: JSON.stringify(response) },
                        success: function () {
                            console.log("Success Post");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            console.log("Post Failed");
                        }

                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(`Error from .auth/me: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
                });
        });
```

Then on success, it Post's the data to Auth/Home in home controller.

```html
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Auth(ExternalLogin login)
        {
            string userRole;
            var role = _context.Employees.Where(x => x.id == login.id)
                        .Select(x => x.HrFlag)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
            if (role == true)
                userRole = "hr";
            else
                userRole = "employee";

            var empId = _context.Employees.Where(x => x.id== login.id)
                        .Select(x => x.EmployeeId)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("user_id", login.id);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("expiry_on", login.ExpiresOn.ToShortTimeString());
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("access_token", login.AccessToken);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("user_role", userRole);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("empId", empId.ToString());

            return View(nameof(HomeHr));
        }
```

Then it grabs the values passed by the ajax call (from /auth/me) into the model then i set the session variables. I then call them in layout.cshtml and home.cshtml

layout.cshtml:

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{ var empId = Context.Session.GetString("empId");}
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("EditHr", "Home", new { id = empId })">My Profile</a>
                    @if (Context.Session.GetString("user_role") == "hr")
                    {
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("employees", "Home")">Employees</a>
```

ExternalLogin model

```html
public class ExternalLogin
    {
        [JsonProperty("access_token", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("provider_name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string ProviderName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("user_id", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("user_claims", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public AuthUserClaim[] UserClaims { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("access_token_secret", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string AccessTokenSecret { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("authentication_token", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("expires_on", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id_token", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string IdToken { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("refresh_token", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    }
```

General flow I am trying to achieve:
When the user goes to the azure hosted website: user logs in, redirected to my app home/index,  /.auth/me captured and displayed in console, ajax posts (/.auth/me) to Home/Auth, set session variables and keep them active until expiry_on = datetime.now.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, the session variables are null

Comment: @kevinchirayath Is there a reason not to use JWT?

Comment: @Win i wanted to try to do this with Session storage. Would using JWT a better approach?

Comment: @kevinchirayath Using session state is a not a good practice in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Win i thought so. It seems like a dirty approach. Can you direct me to the best way to handle AD authentication. Not sure how to approach this in .Net Core 2.1

Comment: @kevinchirayath You might want to look at [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop). It basically registers you app in Azure AD and uses one of OAuth 2 Grant Types depending on your client.

Comment: @Win the user signs in through Microsoft login through a company portal and i need to capture the response from /.auth/me. I am not handling the login portion, just grabbing the info after login and holding the params (i.e. access_token, expiry_on, user_id) in a cookie or somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was a lot simpler than expected. Not sure why there isn't documentation for this, maybe because it was an obvious answer lol.

Here is what I did to grab the .auth/me json on the redirect from Azure Authentication.

Made an ajax call.

```html
$(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'https://mcintranet-stage.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                Login(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Post Failed");
            }

        });

    });
```

Then pass the object - from .auth/me - into a function server side:

```html
    function Login(responseData) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: `@Url.Action("Login", "Account")`,
            data: responseData[0],
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == "Success") {
                    console.log("Success Post");
                    window.location.href = window.location.origin + "/Home/HomeHr";
                }
                else if (response == "Failed")
                    console.log("Failed Post");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Post Failed");
            }
        })
    }
```

Server side to set authorization

```html
[HttpPost]
        public string Login(ExternalLogin login)
        {
            var userToken = login.access_token;
            var empId = login.user_id;
            var emp = _context.Employees.Where(x => x.Id== empId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (UserExists(empId) == true)
            {
                if (empId != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", empId);
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("empId", emp.EmployeeId.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("user_role", IsInRole(emp.Id));
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("name", emp.Fullname);

                }
                return "Success";
            }
            return "Failed";
        }
```